# JQuery Mobile Panel Styling: data-display="reveal" not working properly

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am working on a jQuery Mobile Application and I've got trouble with the panel stylingso far:

http://jsfiddle.net/xt3MM/1/

I have a navigational list, that is appearing from the left. I set data-display to default (data-display="reveal"), but the List seems to be hovering over the body. That way the Shadow of the body is not applied to the list this left menu:

http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0/docs/examples/panels/panel-styling.html#demo-page

```
<!-- RIGHT -->
<div data-role="panel" id="right-panel" data-display="reveal" data-position="right">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-icon="false" data-theme="c">
        <li><a href="#" data-icon="home">Home Right</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-icon="star">Buttons Right</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Facebook Right</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Mail Right</a></li>
        <li data-icon="delete"><a href="#" data-rel="close">Close Right</a></li>
    </ul>
</div><!-- /panel -->


<div class="header" data-role="header" data-position="inline" data-theme="c">

    <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>

    <a href="#right-panel" data-icon="grid" class="header-menu"></a>

</div>
```

I tried settig the z-index lower, but then the menu disappears completely.

Here is a screenshot of the shadow, which is not over the menu.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/D685b.jpg

Kind regards,

George :)

Answer (score 1):

The demo page you gave specify another value of data-display: `data-display="overlay"`

See here a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xt3MM/2/

Comment: I know. But I would like to use data-display="reveal" like here:
http://jsfiddle.net/xt3MM/3/